# Configure and Display the Video Stream of a CSI Camera on BeagleBone AI-64

Tags: camera, beagleboneblack, beagleboard, csi

I'm currently working on a project involving the BeagleBone AI-64 and a CSI camera, but I'm having trouble configuring and displaying the video stream. I've followed the available documentation but I can't find the specific information to load the necessary overlay and get the video stream from the camera.

Could anyone point me in the direction of :

1. Where to find and how to load the appropriate overlay for a CSI camera on BeagleBone AI-64?
2. Code examples or tutorials for displaying the camera's video stream using Python and OpenCV?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated, as I'm stuck at this stage of my project.

Thank you very much!

Here's what I've already tried:

- Physically connect the camera to the BeagleBone AI-64.
- Searching for specific overlays for my CSI camera in the BeagleBoard documentation.
- Tried different commands in terminal with various utilities such as vlc or ffmeg and Python scripts with OpenCV, but without success.